# Сортировка коллекции по N произвольным полям

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции

Имеется коллекция элементов, в которых может быть N полей. К примеру, 5 полей:

```
class Human {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private int height;
    private int condition;
    ...
}
```

В зависимости от выбора пользователя, нужно отсортировать коллекцию от 0 до 5 полей в произвольном порядке, как по возрастанию, так и по убыванию. То есть пользователь может захотеть отсортировать только по полям ***name*** и ***weight***, или по полям ***height***, ***weight***, ***name*** и т.п., причем важен как порядок полей так и порядок сортировки.

Возможно ли как-то ***гибко*** реализовать это?
Или только пошагово - анализируем количество полей, анализируем последовательность полей, анализируем направление сортировки для каждого поля, и в зависимости от всех этих условий уже выбираем заранее написанный `Comparator`?

Comment: Не думаю, что есть способ за исключением написания компатара внутри класса, который бы учитывал все ваши изложенные требования.

Comment: ну не все так драматично. компаратор писать, конечно придется. совсем другой вопрос, как он будет реализован. если у вас действительно такие сложные условия, то этот самый компаратор должен быть сопоставлен с декоратором либо цепочкой обязанностей. по сути метод компаратора возвращает обычный инт. вызывайте из метода compare  декаратор и делигируйте ему исполнение, а уже пусть он вернет инт. разумеется, декоратор должен быть самописный))

Comment: @Oleg Aleksandrov все возможные варианты для 5 полей просто в разной последовательности - 120 вариантов. Это минимум... Поэтому и искал что универсальное.

Answer (score 1):

В классе `Human` имплементируем интерфейс `Comparable` и указываем в нем карту полей для сравнения - `LinkedHashMap` с порядком их значимости и направлениями сортировки. Определяем метод `compareTo`, в котором проводим разбор карты:

```java
public class Human implements Comparable<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> conditions) {
        if (conditions == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int val = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : conditions.entrySet()) {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            switch (entry.getKey()) {
                case ("name:asc"): {
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        val = this.name.compareTo((String) value);
                        if (val != 0) {
                            return val;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ("name:desc"): {
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        val = this.name.compareTo((String) value);
                        if (val != 0) {
                            return val * -1;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ("age:asc"): {
                    if (value instanceof Integer) {
                        val = this.age.compareTo((Integer) value);
                        if (val != 0) {
                            return val;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case ("age:desc"): {
                    if (value instanceof Integer) {
                        val = this.age.compareTo((Integer) value);
                        if (val != 0) {
                            return val * -1;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Human{name=" + name + ",age=" + age + "}";
    }
}
```

Подготавливаем карту полей и направлений сортировки и передаем в метод `compareTo`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Human> humans = new ArrayList<>();
    humans.add(new Human("Sidr", 22));
    humans.add(new Human("John", 23));
    humans.add(new Human("Petr", 24));
    humans.add(new Human("Sidr", 20));

    humans.stream()
        .sorted((h1, h2) -> {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> conditions = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            conditions.put("name:desc", h2.getName());
            conditions.put("age:asc", h2.getAge());
            return h1.compareTo(conditions);
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Human{name=Sidr,age=20}
Human{name=Sidr,age=22}
Human{name=Petr,age=24}
Human{name=John,age=23}
```

---

**Примечание:** `instanceof` - дорогая по времени операция. Вместо нее можно использовать конструкцию `try` `catch`, т. к. при приведении типов могут выбрасываться исключения.